# how to login as root to running pod as root in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I tried multiple syntax including one given below , no luck yet

```
kubectl exec  -u root -it testpod -- bash
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'u' in -u
See 'kubectl exec --help' for usage.
```

it is version 1.22

Comment: Is this Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), minikube or another implementation of Kubernetes (K8s)?  Would you also be able to share the parent image for `testpod`?  When I attempt to `exec` into a Debian Bullseye-based container running inside of a `pod` within GKE and executing `sh` I am automatically logged-in as `root`.

Comment: https://github.com/ottoyiu/kubectl-sshd this may be helpful. Although `runAsUser` seems to be better approach.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no option available in `kubectl exec` to mention the user
- Because it is decided at either in the container image or in the pod.spec.containers.securityContext.runAsUser field
- so to achieve what youy want is on a running container then do just `kubectl exec   -it testpod -- bash`  and then issue `su - root` from inside the container